# Ffmpeg video conversion for minidlna running on openwrt

Tags: ffmpeg

im very close to have my media server running on openwrt in a extrooted tplink.

So far everything is good but can not get all my video files exposed.
After doing some research I noticed that I need specific video parameters (codec , size , etc) to get it to work.

Any one can help me to go from this video settings:

> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p,
>   1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2088 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50
>   tbc (default)

To this:

> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 /
>   0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 620 kb/s, 29.97 fps,
>   29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)

Last format is the one I know is working.

Comment: The resolution may matter but I think the profile is the only relevant attribute: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -profile:v baseline -crf 21 -c:a copy out.mp4`

Comment: it worked !!!! Thanks.